# Schemadesign in laravel [migrations]

Tags: mysql, database, migration, laravel, database-schema

Quick question about schemadesign in laravel. This is the current schema I have for my users table. Now I want to add full user information meaning all the information that is required to bill somebody, firstname, lastname, address, etc.

What is the standard approach to adding tabledata in laravel? Would I create a migration to add columns onto this one. Or roll this migration back and rewrite it with the added columns?

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('activated')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Is there a drawback to either method? Also I'm wondering I'm adding about 9 extra columns for all the added info wich would make my Users table quite large, although it's not necessary at the moment would It be better to put this extra info in another table?

In total this Users table would end up with about 16 columns or so, will this have any negative impact on performance?

Might be some stupid questions, but I don't have a lot of experiences with larger database schema's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you roll this back you would be dropping the table, I do not reccommend doing that, I would add the new columns to the existing table. Otherwise you would be dropping the users table if you decided you don't need this additional information.

Comment: It's on a localhost with minimal data in it so that wouldn't be a big issue but yeah I guess it's good to add onto it incase I don't need the additional information yeah.